# What is the differense between "aired" and "realized" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the difference in meaning of the following sentences?

> The show was aired last year.
>
> The show was realized last year.

Comment: Dictionary defintions?

Comment: I would like to see the original context of "The show was realized last year."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the sentence "The show was aired last year" indicates broadcast over some medium (such as television or radio), "The show was realized last year" is ambiguous and can mean several things.

> **Realized**: 1.  Become aware--to understand a situation, sometimes suddenly
>   2.  Achieve--to achieve something you were hoping for
>   3.  Money--to be sold for a particular amount of money

Without context, it is impossible to know the meaning for the use of the verb "realized".